# Cannot access field productQuantity on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<productSKU STRING, v2ProductName STRING, v2ProductCategory STRING, ...>>

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to use BigQuery to query data from Google Analytics. It gives me this error before I can run it:

> `Cannot access field productQuantity on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<productSKU STRING, v2ProductName STRING, v2ProductCategory STRING, ...>>`

I googled it and I am already using the `UNNEST` function as suggested in some other answers. I am not sure what's wrong.

Also I am querying from different tables in Google Analytics and the data is stored by date. Is there a way that I can query from a specific time frame without repeating the code?

Please see my code below:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  date,
  hits.transaction.transactionId,
  hits.product.productQuantity
FROM
  `XXX1`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
  UNNEST(hits.product.productQuantity) AS prod
GROUP BY
  date
UNION ALL
SELECT
  date,
  hits.transaction.transactionId,
  hits.product.productQuantity
FROM
  `XXX2` UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
  UNNEST(hits.product.productQuantity) AS prod
GROUP BY
  date
UNION ALL
SELECT
  date,
  hits.transaction.transactionId,
  hits.product.productQuantity
FROM
  `XXX3` UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
  UNNEST(hits.product.productQuantity) AS prod
GROUP BY
  date
UNION ALL
SELECT
  date,
  hits.transaction.transactionId,
  hits.product.productQuantity
FROM
  `XXX4` UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
  UNNEST(hits.product.productQuantity) AS prod
GROUP BY
  date
UNION ALL
SELECT
  date,
  hits.transaction.transactionId,
  hits.product.productQuantity
FROM
  `XXX5` UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
  UNNEST(hits.product.productQuantity) AS prod
GROUP BY
  date
UNION ALL
SELECT
  date,
  hits.transaction.transactionId,
  hits.product.productQuantity
FROM
  `XXX6` UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
  UNNEST(hits.product.productQuantity) AS prod
GROUP BY
  date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot access field productQuantity on a value with type ARRAY>

You should use below approach

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  date,
  hits.transaction.transactionId, 
  prod.productQuantity
FROM `XXX`,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
UNNEST(hits.product) AS prod
```

So, as you can see `productQuantity` is accessed using unnested 'prod'

NOTE: when you using GROUP BY you need to use aggregation functions for those fileds in your select statement which are not part of the GROUP BY - In your example there are two fields below that needs to be applied with whatever aggregation you are looking for in case if you still need GROUP BY

```
hits.transaction.transactionId, 
prod.productQuantity
```

> Is there a way that I can query from a specific time frame without repeating the code?

Yes, You can use [_TABLE_SUFFIX](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference) for this

like in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  date,
  hits.transaction.transactionId, 
  prod.productQuantity
FROM `project.dataset.XXX*`,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
UNNEST(hits.product) AS prod   
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '1' AND '6'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But the file I exported contains a lot more columns that I have selected (using the same code as you suggested). It basically has everything about products. Is it because I use UNNEST? If I just want date, transactionId and productQuantity, what should I do?